# How can I render markdown in express.js jade template?

Tags: parsing, node.js, render, markdown, express

I use the express js framework. I have a markdownified string from the database and want to render it as HTML in my jade template. I installed node-markdown and want to render it this way:

**app.js**

```
var md = require("node-markdown").Markdown;
```

**template.jade**

```
- each note in todo.notes
  div= md(note.string)
```

However, it doesn't print out anything... any advice at this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** solved it myself, just forgot to get the md variable into my view...

Comment: I recommend you answer and accept your own question. With a mention of how to inject md variable into the view.

Comment: can you post your answer on how you achieved this?

Comment: For people coming here in 2016: Jade is now [Pug](https://pugjs.org/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

The problem was, I forgot to pass the **md** variable into my view. so what you have to do to get the node-markdown module running is the following:

**app.js header**

```
var md = require("node-markdown").Markdown;
```

**app.js route** (passing the md variable)

```
...
res.render('template', { vars: { foo: foo_.bar }, md: md, layout: false });
...
```

**template.jade**

```
...
div!= md(note.string)
...
```

Comment: thanks for posting what you did.  i can get my markdown to render onto the page, but all outputs as html entities so you see the actual markup on the page.  did you encounter anything like this?

Comment: i figured out why it was outputting as escaped html - i didn't have `div!= md(str)` to keep the renderer from sanitizing the html.

Comment: if you use a variable often it might be a good idea to write it into app.locals?
this way you can just access it as md from your views as well and wont have to pass it to every view.

Comment: Depending on your rendering needs, you don't need the `div`, it is possible to simply use it like so: `!= md(note.string)`

Answer (score 14):

There is the concept of 'filters' that expose a 'compiler' or 'filter' visitor to a portion of the jade template.

Check out: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

**filters**

:sass must have sass.js installed

:less must have less.js installed

:markdown must have [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) installed or node-discount

:cdata

:coffeescript must have coffee-script installed

You use it via this syntax in a template:
http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/

Comment: While this answer is correct, it does not specifically answer the question since `Filters are compile time. This makes them fast but means they cannot support dynamic content.`

Answer (score 7):

The node module `node-markdown` is deprecated. The [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) is advanced new version. You can try like this

```
var md = require('marked');
```

Inside your router

```
res.render('template', { md: md });
```

Inside your jade template

```
div!= md(note.string)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked), in your Jade file, you can do something as simple as this:

```
extends layout

block content
    include:md ../../public/docs/getting-started.md
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get something like `md is not a filter`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked), then you can do the following instructions:

#### app.js

```
app.locals.md = require('marked').setOptions({ breaks: true })
```

Now you can call the function everytime you want it on template jade, example in your case:

#### template.jade

```
- each note in todo.notes
    div!= md(note.string)
```